# Using an std::vector of pointer objects. Is there a way to delete an item from the vector when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm making the mental transition from *old school* C++ to "*modern*".

I have a class factory that is used to make sure all instances of a certain class, `foo`, are maintained in a list.  This list is used to process all `foo`s in order.

This is in a legacy system that uses regular old pointers (`new`/`delete`) but I was thinking of turning them into `shared_ptr`s.

Will I still need a "`RemoveMeFromList()`" call in the `foo`'s destructor or is there some magic I'm not aware of?

Comment: if you keep `shared_ptr`s in the vector, the pointers NEVER go out of scope. It always keeps a ref count on the objects.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, the `c++XX` version tags should only be used for questions the relate to a specific version of C++, e.g. "How did the meaning of `auto` change in C++14"? This doesn't seem to be the case for your question.

Comment: There's no way to tell a vector to automatically remove empty smart pointers, if that's what you're asking. You'll need to do that yourself

Comment: why not use `unique_ptr`?

Comment: >Why not use unique_ptr?Thank you for the question.  I don't think a unique_ptr fits my situation.  I forgot to mention that the factory returns a pointer to the created object to the calling function.  The factory is not the only user of the pointer.

Comment: @Gupta Careful here: "_the pointers NEVER go out of scope_" Scope isn't a concept applicable to pointer values; a variable has a scope. An object has a lifetime. When the lifetime of a "smart pointer" (not a pointer and not really smart), something happens (another object lifetime is ended, or a counter value is changed, or something else).

Answer (score 2):

What I propose you in this case is to keep a vector of weak pointers (`std::weak_ptr`) in your factory:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<foo>> foo_instances;
```

Now, with this vector, if one pointer goes out of the scope, it will be expired. So, you can remove the expired pointers next time that you process the vector. In other words, you do not need an explicit "RemoveMeFromList" method, but you can do the removal of expired pointers when you go for processing of the foo instances.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I still need a "RemoveMeFromList" call in the foo's destructor

Yes.

> or is there some magic I'm not aware of?

No.

You could implement a custom container, that stores weak pointers to objects in shared ownership, and on every access, check whether the pointer is still valid. I don't know if this would be a good design for you (seems dubious).

Answer (score 1):

> This is in a legacy system that uses regular old pointers (new/delete) but I was thinking of turning them into `shared_ptr`s.

You have not really provided us with a lot to go on, but I suspect `std::shared_ptr` is not what you need. `std::shared_ptr` is used to "collaboratively manage" ownership by all copies of the pointer, and kill it when there are none. Such killing will not notify your "factory", or central repository, of `foo`s. But since you actually have it, and you want it to keep track of the instances, just let *it* be the one owning them. At most, you could have the entities which get pointers/references to `foo` instances instead get wrappers which handle just ref-counting somehow. Your central `foo` repository will handle deletions - if they are at all necessary. It could recycle unused `foo`s - reinitialize them and hand them out instead of really allocating anything new.

Again, sorry for the rather vague and abstract answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a solution with shared_ptr and weak_ptr as eerorika suggested by doing something like this. You might prefer this solution to unique_ptr if you don't want the Factory to be the owner of the objects which determines *when* things are invalid.

Your factory class could look something like this:

```
class Factory {
   public:
      std::shared_ptr<MyObject> create();
      std::vector<std::weak_ptr<MyObject>>& getObjects();
   private:
      std::vector<std::weak_ptr<MyObject>> objects;
      void cullInvalidObjects();
};
```

We simply create a weak_ptr from the shared_ptr of the object in the factory method:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyObject> Factory::create()
{
   auto object = std::make_shared<MyObject>();
   std::weak_ptr<MyObject> weakObject = object;
   objects.push_back(weakObject);
   return object;
};
```

The factory can have an internal method that culls objects that are no longer valid:

```
void Factory::cullInvalidObjects()
{
    auto iter = objects.begin();
    while (iter != objects.end())
    {
        if ((*iter).expired())
        {
            objects.erase(iter++);
        }
    }
}
```

and then when getting objects to work on them, you would probably want to cull the list before providing it:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<MyObject>>& Factory::getObjects()
{
   cullInvalidObjects()
   return objects;
}
```

Alternatively, rather than culling you could just get the list and then check for validity in your functions that process it. This is probably not the best solution if you have a large number of invalid items.

```
void callSomeMethod(std::vector<std::weak_ptr<MyObject>>& objects)
{
   for (auto wObj : objects)
   {
       auto sObj = wObj.lock();
       if(p)
       {
         p->someMethod();
       }
   }
}
```